# Porque mi servidor HTTP no funciona en segundo plano?

Tags: python, servidor, http, excepciones

estoy intentando crear un pequeño servidor para enviar mensajes simples, y funciona a la perfección hasta que lo pongo en segundo plano. he intentado hacer que funcione en segundo plano con las librerías `win32`, y con la extensión de archivo `.pyw`, pero nada funciona, al conectarme al servidor por navegador, me tira el error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` es como si el servidor no existiera. podrían ayudarme? gracias.
este es mi código:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import pyautogui
message = None
class RequestHandler_httpd(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    global message
    message = self.requestline
    message = message[5 : int(len(message) - 9)]
    messagetosend = bytes('Escribe un messageje',"utf")
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(messagetosend))
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(messagetosend)
    if message=='' or message=='favicon.ico':
      pass
    else:
      pyautogui.alert(message, message, message)
    return
server_address_httpd = ('215.179.1.1',8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address_httpd, RequestHandler_httpd)
print('iniciado')
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: ¿ Que significa `en segundo plano` ?

Comment: Renombrar como .pyw y haciendo doble clic en él debería funcionar. Si no funciona quizás es que cuando lo lanzas desde una terminal tienes activado un entorno virtual en el que está instalado pyautogui, pero al lanzarlo desde el explorador de archivos no. En todo caso no veo que estés usando para nada pyautogui, así que prueba a quitar ese import.

Answer (score 0):

@Juanjo es decir, que no se muestra el programa en pantalla, pero sigue estando activo. Un programa que corre en segundo plano no se puede ver en pantalla pero si se puede ver el proceso en el administrador de tareas.

Comment: ¿Eres el mismo usuario de la pregunta?

Comment: Si, acabe de crear la cuenta pero no sé que pasó. Se creo una cuenta totalmente aparte y ahora no puedo acceder a la otra.

Comment: Reporté a un mod. diamantado para que por favor te apoye con esa situación, ahora al margen recuerda que toda aclaración debe ir en la pregunta (así que cuando logres tener de vuelta la cuenta te recomiendo la edites) y de paso ahorita puedes eliminar esta no respuesta ;)

Comment: @BetaM está bien

Comment: Listo!!! elimina esta respuesta... en unos dias estaran fusionadas las cuentas